# Image gallery using sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4

I am new bee to sencha touch. I have started with few samples and now kindda familiar with store model and few other UI controls. As i am not a web developer I feel difficult most of the times to understand the small small things.

Now, I want to design a image gallery for iPhone using sencha Touch and java script.  Please give me some sample of the layouts that i have to use. The images used will be fetched from my content server.

I got some example here [Sencha Touch Gallery](http://dl.box.com/dl/872671039/85cbe75cf95b92747794a162c4973628?a=7b882f0b643b57d4d04217855039e6e2&m=10.12.30.52,11211&x=1&c=d8eeae2e760482be5d56a5d03f615d0c). but it uses php scripts which i cant understand. Please guild me to start with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about PHP.

First try to load statik images as you want.
After that you could take any image lists with stores from server.

I do not think there is a component which creates a layout like example given by you above. But you could create with using some different components together.

Did you see [this example](http://touchstyle.mobi/app/)

In my opinion you must start developing some screens and then ask questions about problems you faced.

Best wishes.